# read a whole line of a csv file and save it to a DataSet

Tags: java, csv, dataset, deep-netts

I want to program a KI for checking if emails are spam or not. I am using deepNetts. I have a csv training set, which is very large. As you see in the bottom, I used deepNetts function ReadCsv to read the csv. But it only reads one column of a line, but I need it to read the whole line. How do I achieve this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.visrec.ml.data.DataSet;
import deepnetts.data.DataSets;
import deepnetts.data.preprocessing.scale.MaxScaler;
import deepnetts.net.FeedForwardNetwork;
import deepnetts.net.layers.activation.ActivationType;
import deepnetts.net.loss.LossType;
import deepnetts.net.train.BackpropagationTrainer;

public class Main {
    public Main() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String csvFile = "emails.csv";
        DataSet emailsDataSet= DataSets.readCsv(csvFile , 3000, 1, true); 
        DataSet[] trainAndTestSet = emailsDataSet.split(0.6, 0.4);

        MaxScaler scaler = new MaxScaler(trainAndTestSet[0]);
        scaler.apply(trainAndTestSet[0]);
        scaler.apply(trainAndTestSet[1]);

        FeedForwardNetwork neuralNet = FeedForwardNetwork.builder()
                                                 .addInputLayer(3000)                          
                                                                                                                                                       
                                                 .addFullyConnectedLayer(50) 

                                                 .addOutputLayer(1,   ActivationType.SIGMOID) 
                                                                                 
                                                   .lossFunction(LossType.CROSS_ENTROPY) 
                                                 .build();
          neuralNet.getTrainer().setMaxError(0.03f)
                                  .setMaxEpochs(10000)
                                  .setLearningRate(0.001f);

          neuralNet.train(trainAndTestSet[0]);
    }
}
```

I get this error in the console:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3000 out of bounds
```

Comment: Are there 3000 values in each row? If not, change that 3000 to the number of values in the row, or that number - 1.